# user Enable\disable parts of the code in batch

Tags: batch-file, configuration, user-controls

In my batch I use text to speech. But is there a way to  set in a syntax that gives the user an option to enable or disable text to speech in the batch  without have to  write the same syntax all over the code 100  times?

edit:

```
random program

ok so heres the problem. below theres just something i threw together that got no function exept for explaining what i intend to do.
what i wonder is that: when the user starts the main program.  (with main menu)  he/she will get the option to toggle on/off the "text to speech for the entire program.

etc

if user of the program chooses to disable the text to speech function. and then decides to run program1. (as u can see theres a text to speech part in program1)
but since he previously in main menu selected DISABLE for voice. then it will not play the voice in program 1,2 or 3. even the script is there. it gets sort of "turned off" until user chooses to turn this function back on. (without manual edit of each line)

is this possiblie? im quite sorry if u didnt understand my explaination. im not very good at explaining. but i hope you understood it :P

========================================================================================================================================

:main
title random program 
(heres the menu of the program)


:program 1:
REM (random program script here)

set text="this is the part i wish to be able for users to toggle on/off"
goto num
:num
set num=%random%
if exist temp%num%.vbs goto num
echo ' > "temp%num%.vbs"
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >> "temp%num%.vbs"
echo speech.speak "%text%" >> "temp%num%.vbs"
start temp%num%.vbs
pause>nul
del temp%num%.vbs
goto program2


:program2
REM (random program script here)

set text="this is the part i wish to be able for users to toggle on/off"
goto num
:num
set num=%random%
if exist temp%num%.vbs goto num
echo ' > "temp%num%.vbs"
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >> "temp%num%.vbs"
echo speech.speak "%text%" >> "temp%num%.vbs"
start temp%num%.vbs
pause>nul
del temp%num%.vbs
goto program4

:program3
REM (random program script here)

set text="this is the part i wish to be able for users to toggle on/off"
goto num
:num
set num=%random%
if exist temp%num%.vbs goto num
echo ' > "temp%num%.vbs"
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >> "temp%num%.vbs"
echo speech.speak "%text%" >> "temp%num%.vbs"
start temp%num%.vbs
pause>nul
del temp%num%.vbs
goto main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. You want to execute some lines depending on user choice? You can do this with a little trick:

```
@echo off
choice /c YN /M "Enable?"
if errorlevel 2 (set "do=REM") else (set "do=")
echo Hello
%do% echo maybe...
```

**EDIT**
Implementation of my answer into your script (I took the freedom to change it a bit - no need to write the same code over and over again)

```
@echo off
:main
choice /c YN /M "Enable speech?"
if errorlevel 2 (set "do=REM") else (set "do=")

title random program 
echo (heres the menu of the program)

:program 1:
echo REM (random program script 1 here)
set text="you just executed random script one"
%do% call :speak
goto program2

:program2
echo REM (random program script 2 here)
set text="This was the second random script"
%do% call :speak
goto program3

:program3
echo REM (random program script 3 here)
set text="And this is the third of them."
%do% call :speak
rem goto main
goto :eof

:Speak
set num=%random%
if exist speak%num%.vbs goto :speak
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") > "speak%num%.vbs"
echo speech.speak %text% >> "speak%num%.vbs"
speak%num%.vbs 
del speak%num%.vbs
```

Instead of using `choice` you can of course also implement it into your menue.

Comment: yes im sorry for the bad explaination. i tried to explain a bit better in the edit. hope that helps

Comment: Simply genioys!  Thanks!

Comment: oh i just overlooked something the "echo REM (random program heree) what am i suposed to use that for and how?

Comment: ? Exactly the same, as you intended to do in your original script for `REM (random program script here)` (I just added an `echo` to see, what happens)

Comment: Oh LOL my bad i fptgot about that xD